# C++ generic array implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, generics

I came lately across a C++ recruitment test. They are asking the 4 following questions.

1. There are at least 4 different bugs in the implementation of the
   following Array class.
2. Provide for at least 2 of them a test case for each bug.
3. Propose a ﬁx for each bug
4. Assuming we have a bug-free implementation of Array class, do you think
   there are any design problems with it?

```
template <class T> class Array {
private:
    T *m_pData;
    unsigned int m_nSize;

public:

    Array(unsigned int nSize) : m_nSize( nSize)
    { 
        if ( m_nSize > 0)
            m_pData = new ( nothrow) T[ m_nSize];
    } 

    virtual ~Array() 
    { 
        if(m_pData != NULL)
            delete m_pData; 
    } 

    bool Set(unsigned int nPos, const T& Value) 
    {
        if(nPos < m_nSize) {
            m_pData[nPos] = Value;
            return true;
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }

    T Get(unsigned int nPos) {
        if(nPos < m_nSize) {
            return m_pData[nPos];
        }
        else 
            return T();
    }
};
```

The problem is I can see no bug.
Yes, there are some weird code like:

- checking before calling delete
- returning a default value in Get when outofbounds
- using delete instead of delete []

But these are no bugs to me.

Comment: (1) `delete m_pData;` should be `delete [] m_pData;`

Comment: Look at your constructor.  What happens if `m_nSize == 0`?  What will the `m_pData` pointer be set to?  Also, there is no need to test for NULL when issuing a `delete`.  The code has bugs **and** style issues.

Comment: There is not a copy-constructor or assignment operator.

Comment: What happens if `new (nothrow)` returns nullptr?

Comment: Default-constructing a `T` to return for an out-of-bounds `Get` seems ridiculous.

Comment: So do non-const `Get` and non-explicit ctor. It's un-lovely code even without the bugs.

Comment: Using that class as it stands, the following `main` function is undefined behavior `int main() { Array<int> a(0);}`  Goes back to my comment of passing 0 to the constructor.

Comment: checking for null values before deleting is not a bug, but unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the five bugs that I can find at a glance:

1. Creating an instance with `nSize == 0` will not initialise `m_pData`.
2. If allocation fails, `m_nSize` is set to a wrong value, and subsequent access will fail.
3. Copy constructor is missing.
4. Assignment operator is missing.
5. `delete` should be `delete[]` (and yes, the `NULL` check is redundant).

Those are all actual bugs, no argument possible. The other weaknesses (that I can see) are “merely” crippling design flaws.

Answer (score 0):

General:
1. it is the best to put curly braces on each if-else , even for 1 line of code. - (arguable) 
2. this `if(m_pData != NULL)` is redundand. C++ checks for null pointers in delete and delete[]
3. you should opt `nullptr` isntead of `NULL`. 
4.Get could have been declared as const. not a bug per-se
5.does people still use the hungarian notation? 

Bugs:
1.  `delete m_pData;` should be `delete[] m_pData;`
according to the standard, deleting instead of deleting[] anything that was allocated with new[] has undefined behaviour.
2. in the Constructor : new doesn't throw exception in case of insufficiant memory, yet m_nSize is set to the given size anyway. that may lead to future bugs - if you try to allocate 10000 objects and you fails, Get and Set still going to excess `*(m_pData + nPos)` but this memory address is invalid.
it should be actually :
 `if( m_pData ) {m_nSize = nSize ;}`
3. `m_pData[nPos];` in Get and Set: again - the constructor doesn't throw an exception and `m_pData` may be null .you need to check if `m_pData` is not null.

Extended answer:
I do realize this is a test to check the person's understanding in memory management , obejct oriented and some template use. yet, the best answer will be "there is no need to reinvent the wheel, `std::vector` is smarter from any naive implementation we might think of."
saying this as addition for the bugs above really raise your answer to a something that a professional C++ developer would say.

Comment: Disagree (strongly) with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Four Errors : 
1. template class Array { private: T *m_pData; unsigned int m_nSize;
It should be

```
template <class T>
class Array 
{
    private: T *m_pData; unsigned int m_nSize;
```

2.In below code segment

```
Array(unsigned int nSize) : m_nSize( nSize)
{ 
    if ( m_nSize > 0)
        m_pData = new ( nothrow) T[ m_nSize];
}
```

if m_nSize  is less then 0 , assigne m_pData to null;

3.In below cpode :

```
virtual ~Array() 
{ 
    if(m_pData != NULL)
        delete m_pData; 
}
```

Instead of delete , use delete[] m_pData , as m_pDatais array.

4. in both get and set functions check whether m_pData is NULL or not null before accessing.

Comment: (1) was just a formatting error in the question, not an actual error in the code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ok fine

Comment: `m_nSize` can't be less than 0 since it is unsigned.